# How can I rearrange the dimensions of an array in R?

Tags: r, dimensions

I have temperature data (mg$Data) in a list:

[image]

I got rid of the singleton dimensions with:

```
mg$Data<-drop(mg$Data)
```

After processing it is of the size:[1:12,1:256,1:512]

[image]

Where the `i` dimension is months, `j` is latitude and `k` is longitude.

I want to rearrange this data for output to a netcdf file, but I want it in the format: lat,lon,time. i.e. [1:256,1:512,1:12]

So. Here's a reproducible example: if I create a NaN dataset of the same size:

```
data <- rep(NaN, 12*256*512);
```

Can I do this?

```
ar <- array(data, c(12,256,512));
```

Would this maintain the proper positioning of the data? I'm relatively new to R, so I may be missing something basic here.

Comment: `aperm()` is your friend.

Comment: That transposed it to 512x256x12 (as opposed to 256x512x12). But as it turns out, that's exactly what I needed to map out the .nc outputs. Many thanks.